# Apply height to div after it's loaded by Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I got a shopping cart layer that loads by ajax and shows up in the middle of the screen when clicking a button.
I am trying to apply height to it. Successfully managed to do that when I resize the window, but need to apply the same code instantly when that layer loads.
The function calculates the content area size, so I can't use it on page load or at any other time, except for the same time it is loaded.

This is my function that works fine for the window resize event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $(window).resize(function() {
          var bodyheight = $(window).height();
          var cartheight = $('.shopping-cart-main-content').prop('scrollHeight');
          var cartpercent = ((cartheight + 100) / bodyheight) * 100;

          if (cartpercent > 90) {
            $(".main-shopping-cart").css({'height': '90%'});
          }else{
            $(".main-shopping-cart").css({'height': cartpercent + '%'});
          }
       }); 
    });
```

Any suggestions how to apply it when the ajax layer appears?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the same code that changes the height into your AJAX call's success function